# String in String , by searching each occurrence of specific text and filter to other cells

Tags: string, excel, vba

```
Summary : Using vba-excel Looping through a single cell of text , finding 
and taking  out  each nth occurrence of <li> to </li > into each individual 
cell
```

**Before**

Single excel cell (e.g A1 ) contains

```
<li>
  <ahref="xxxx">
  <imgsrc=""yyy">
  </a>
</li>

<li>
  <ahref="xxxx">
  <imgsrc=""yyy">
  </a>
</li>
```

**Result ( after ) :**

*cell A2*

```
<ahref="xxxx">
<imgsrc=""yyy">
```

*cell A3*

```
<ahref="xxxx">
<imgsrc=""yyy">
```

much appreciated ; D

what i have done so far

```
'myrow is already pre-define previous , basically row number fetch during 
 loopping

Dim newi As String
Dim texti as string
```

i = MyRow
    texi = cell (i , 1)

```
'not sure if this is correct , trying to find each
For Each item In Texti 
Cells(i, 13) = item("<a href=")
Cells(i, 14) = item("<img src=")
newi = Cells(i, 13).Value + "  " + Cells(i, 14).Value
Next
```

Thanks again in advance for helping me , was stuck with this ~ !

Comment: Is it your homework?

Comment: helping my brother 's vba , but my knowledge is pretty limited

Comment: having my term break , since i am free wanted to do sth and learn sth

Comment: Can't see your efforts...

Comment: hmm , give me 10 mins let me try again , i do have some code but fail to produce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub StringExtract()

Dim iLength As Integer, iLoopCounter As Integer, iInnerLoopCounter As Integer
Dim sRemString As String
Dim iLastRow As Integer

iLength = Len(Range("A1"))

For iLoopCounter = 1 To iLength

    If (Mid(Range("A1"), iLoopCounter, 4) = "<li>") Then

        For iInnerLoopCounter = iInnerLoopCounter + 4 To iLength

            If (Mid(Range("A1"), iInnerLoopCounter, 5) = "</li>") Then

                sRemString = Mid(Range("A1"), iLoopCounter + 5, iInnerLoopCounter - iLoopCounter - 6)

                iLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

                Cells(iLastRow, "A").Value = sRemString

                Exit For

            End If

        Next iInnerLoopCounter

    End If

Next iLoopCounter
End Sub
```

might not be the fastest way, but in this case it should work. I cant figure out, why the `</a>` should be excluded as well. If you need to, increase the integer from -6 to your needs in this line:

```
sRemString = Mid(Range("A1"), iLoopCounter + 5, iInnerLoopCounter - iLoopCounter - 6)
```

Comment: hi  prextor ,  i will try out.
apparently my brother wants that part of the code so just following what he wants hahaha